# Grid view and class library

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using class library and asp.net form.
In class library I created class for retrieving the database value based on specific fileID.I have no idea about how to connect the class to the gridview.Tried using gridview.databind(obj).not working.
Appreciate your help
Thanks

In the asp.net form

```
       Dim retobj As New Mailbox
       retobj.MailboxName = Mailb.Text

    insmairet = New clsMailboxCollect
    insmairet.Retrievemail(retobj)
     gridview1.databind(retobj)
```

Comment: You should show us much more of what you have tried and where you've got stuck. Also if you say `GridView`, are you using ASP.NET? If so, add that tag.

Comment: You cannot connect you class directly to GridView, you need to creare use you class as Data Model and then retrieve IEnumerable or IQuerybale data and pass its is data source to GridView.

Comment: Thanks andrey.Can u explain a bit more because I  have to use Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way for you to use `SqlDataSource` and `GridView`.

You can use it as follows:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataReader"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName, Title FROM Employees">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:GridView
      id="GridView1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  </asp:GridView>
```

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

**EDIT** 
If you would like to use your custom implementation for access data you can use `ObjectDataSource`.

```
    <asp:gridview
      id="GridView1"
      runat="server"
      datasourceid="ObjectDataSource1" />

    <asp:objectdatasource
      id="ObjectDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      selectmethod="GetAllEmployees"
      typename="MyDataBaseLogic" />
```

In this case  `MyDataBaseLogic` will be:

```
public class MyDataBaseLogic
{
    // Returns a collection of NorthwindEmployee objects. 
    public static ICollection GetAllEmployees () {
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Sorry for C#, but you can simply convert it to VB.

Comment: OP asking about how he should use his class as data source, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've changed the answer.